# Magento 2 - Custom REST api POST method not working

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2.3, rest-api

I have created a custom rest api module. When i am using GET method it's working fine. But when i am trying to use POST method it giving below error

> Request does not match any route.

Does anyone have any idea why it is not working?

My **webapi.xml**

Second method (GET) working but First method (POST) not working

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/test/info" method="POST">
        <service class="Bwip\ApiEndpoints\Api\CustomInterface" method="info"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/test/data" method="GET">
        <service class="Bwip\ApiEndpoints\Api\CustomInterface" method="data"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

My di.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Bwip\ApiEndpoints\Api\CustomInterface" type="Bwip\ApiEndpoints\Model\Api\Custom"/>
</config>
```

Interface file

```
interface CustomInterface{

    /**
     * GET for Post api
     * @param string $value
     * @return string
     */

    public function info();
    /**
     * GET for Post api
     * @param string $value
     * @return string
     */

    public function data();
}
```

My Model

```
<?php
namespace Bwip\ApiEndpoints\Model\Api;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Bwip\ApiEndpoints\Api\CustomInterface;
 
class Custom implements CustomInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $name User name.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
    protected $request;

    public function __construct( 
        RequestInterface $request,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->request = $request;
    
    } 
    public function info(){
        $post= $this->request->getPost();
        
        $info[] = array('message' => 'POST Working.', 'status'=> 0);
        return $info;

    }
    public function data(){
        $post= $this->request->getPost();
        
        $info[] = array('message' => 'GET Working.', 'status'=> 0);
        return $info;

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying them, using something like postman? Can you please add the REST Call?

Comment: @AlanZavagli yes, I am using postman
http://domain.com/rest/V1/test/data (Method GET, works)
http://domain.com/rest/V1/test/info (Method POST, does not works)

Comment: Hello have you pass the preference of interfaces in di.xml file

Comment: can you please add here more file code for rest api i thing 3-4 files are reuired

Comment: @JayParmar Please see now. I have updated my question details. Thanks

Comment: @Nayem323 let me check and update here ok

Comment: @JayParmar my get method is working fine, but post not working

Comment: Hello @Nayem323 have you apply this three command after creating this api code

Comment: php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f

Comment: I ran setup:upgrade, c:c and c:f

Comment: please run di:compile and try again because that same code I run and got success

Comment: POST method worked for you? What is your magento version? I am using 2.3.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118775/discussion-between-nayem323-and-jay-parmar).

Answer (score 0):

Please find solution here

custom.php

```
public function info(){
        echo "string";

    }
```

CatalogInterface.php

```
 /**
     * GET for Post api
     * @param string $value
     * @return string
     */

    public function info();
```

in postman pass some raw data for post method you used

[image]

in post man header you pass like that

[image]

and in Authorization please select no-Auth option

[image]

Comment: Did everything as same as this still same problem

Comment: you r issued in url please pass url like that domain.com/rest/V1/test/info